# Does pairwise independence and same distribution imply trivial Invariant $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I know that by Kolmogorov’s $0-1$ Law, that for independent r.v, the tail $\sigma$-algebra is trivial (e.g all events have probability either $0$ or $1$). This coupled with the ergodic theorem, one can easily derive the Strong Law of Large Numbers for $X_i$ i.i.d. and finite expected value.

I also know that there exists a stronger SLLN called Etemadi’s SLLN, which only requires finite expected value, and that $X_i$ have the same distribution and are pairwise independent.

With this in mind, I was wondering if pairwise independence and same distribution imply trivial Invariant $\sigma$-algebra? If it does, can anyone provide a proof or a reference to such proof? And if no, can one provide a counter-example?

Comment: is SLLN true if you only have pairwise independence and same distribution (but not necessarily finite expected value)?

Comment: I don’t think so. Etemadi’s proof of SLLN requires finite expected value.

Comment: ok, so to answer your question, can't you just prove that the answer to my question is 'no'?

Comment: sorry, I don’t know if I quite understood your point. Are you saying that proving the necessity of finite expectation for pairwise independent with same distribution would imply that the they imply trivial tail sigma-algebra?

Comment: Do you have any ready examples of sequences $(X_n)$ that are identically distributed and pairwise independent, but not iid?

Comment: Not really... But I guess you can make some kind of Martingale or Markov sequence with such property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that unfortunately the answer is no. You can construct a pairwise independent sequence of random variables, such that the $\sigma$-algebra is not trivial.

The processes is shown in this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0167715285900173?via%3Dihub) by Robertson  and  Womack (1985). They construct a stochastic process such that $P(X_n=1)=P(X_n=-1)=1/2$, and in a way that the sequence is pairwise independent, but in the very end of the paper, they prove that this stochastic process does not satisfy the 0-1 law.